# Including detection limits and/or inequality metadata in R

Tags: r, attributes, metadata, inequality

I have a large and complex water quality data set that I am trying to import from an excel horror show into R. Most variables have various bits of metadata associated with them. Some of this makes sense to be put in its own column (eg. column1 = Magnesium; column2 = Magnesium.method) while other metadata makes sense to attach directly to the observation value (eg. units, detection limits). Units are easy because of the fantastic "units" package, but detection limits should, presumably, also be attached directly to the observation, however I'm not clear on how best to do this.

Let's say we have a result that has come back as below the detection limit of 6. At the most basic what I am looking for is something like this (though presumably not actually using attr()):

```
Value1 <- NA
attr(Value1, "Lower detection limit") <- 6
Value1
[1] NA
Conservative value:
[1] 6
Mid-range value:
[1] 3
Lowest value:
[1] 0
set_conservativeness("mid")
Value1 + 1
[1] 4
set_conservativeness("low")
Value1 +1
[1] 1
```

It seems like this must be a very common problem, but I have not been able to find any R package that solves it. Maybe I'm just barking up the wrong tree with wanting it to be an attribute of a value rather than an extra column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think it's a great idea to keep the data and the metadata together. It also sounds as though you want to have some specific methods that you can apply to the measurements as well.

Effectively, what you are describing is the creation of your own class. There are a few ways to create your own class in R. The simplest is probably to make an S3 class.

This involves having a constructor function that allows you to set the measurements, the units and the ranges, which it stores as attributes on the returned object. You'll also want a `format` method, a `print` method and an `as.data.frame` method as well as any custom functions you want to apply to the class.

Here's a fairly naive but functional example:

```r
Measurement <- function(x, units = "mmol/l", range_min = 0, range_max = Inf)
{
  structure(x, class = "Measurement", units = units, 
            range_min = range_min, range_max = range_max)
}

format.Measurement <- function(x, ...)
{
  paste0(as.numeric(x), " ", attr(x, "units"), 
         " [", attr(x, "range_min"), " - ", attr(x, "range_max"), "]")
}

print.Measurement <- function(x, quote = FALSE)
{
  print(format(x), quote = quote)
}

as.data.frame.Measurement <- function(x, ...)
{
  structure(list(x), class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, length(x)))
}
```

So now you can create a vector of `Measurement` values like this:

```
M <- Measurement(c(1.2, 3.6, 4.5, 2.0, 2.1, NA), units = "pmol/l", 0.1, 10)
M
#> [1] 1.2 pmol/l [0.1 - 10] 3.6 pmol/l [0.1 - 10] 4.5 pmol/l [0.1 - 10]
#> [4] 2 pmol/l [0.1 - 10]   2.1 pmol/l [0.1 - 10] NA pmol/l [0.1 - 10]
```

and store them in a data frame:

```
data.frame(Measurement = M, ID = LETTERS[1:6])
#>             Measurement ID
#> 1 1.2 pmol/l [0.1 - 10]  A
#> 2 3.6 pmol/l [0.1 - 10]  B
#> 3 4.5 pmol/l [0.1 - 10]  C
#> 4   2 pmol/l [0.1 - 10]  D
#> 5 2.1 pmol/l [0.1 - 10]  E
#> 6  NA pmol/l [0.1 - 10]  F
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. That looks like exactly what I need. I'll give it a go.